# Test exported from Postman fails in Newman

Tags: postman, newman

We exported a collection of tests from Postman (using a JSON file with tests and a separate JSON file with environment variables), try to run like `newman run tests.json -e environment.json` with that set.

The output is confusing:

```
┌─────────────────────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│                         │ executed │   failed │
├─────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│              iterations │        1 │        0 │
├─────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│                requests │       12 │        6 │
├─────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│            test-scripts │        6 │        0 │
├─────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│      prerequest-scripts │        0 │        0 │
├─────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│              assertions │       28 │        0 │
├─────────────────────────┴──────────┴──────────┤
│ total run duration: 819ms                     │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ total data received: 9.8KB (approx)           │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ average response time: 156ms                  │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The amount of assertions passed (28) suggests all tests are OK. But... there are actually only 6 requests in the collection, so it seems that requests are executed twice and one of the executions fails, due to not expanding the variables somehow...

This is what the output says (6 times):

```
1.  Error Invalid URI "http:///%7B%7Bendpoint%7D%7D/products/4"                                                                                   
     at request inside ""
```

So this means that the environment variables are not filled in in those requests.

A snippet of the tests.json file looks like:

```
 {
    "name": "AppStore BackEnd BAKERY_PRODUCT 4 test",
    "event": [
    {
       "listen": "test",
       "script": {
         "id": "0e074806-1248-4446-865d-9e0f3d733ba2", "exec":[
           "pm.sendRequest(\"http://{{endpoint}}/products/4\", function (err, response) {",
                                                    "    ",
                                                    "    pm.test(\"Status code is 200\", function () {",
                                                    "        pm.response.to.have.status(200);",
                                                    "    });",
                                                    "    ",
                                                    "});"
                                            ],
                                            "type": "text/javascript"
                                    }
                            }
                    ],
                    "request": {
                            "method": "GET",
                            "header": [],
                            "body": {
                                    "mode": "raw",
                                    "raw": ""
                            },
                            "url": {
                                    "raw": "http://{{endpoint}}/products/4",
                                    "protocol": "http",
                                    "host": [
                                            "{{endpoint}}"
                                    ],
                                    "path": [
                                            "products",
                                            "4"
                                    ]
                            }
                    },
                    "response": []
            },
```

Any clues???

Comment: What does that test look like in the Postman UI? Is `{{endpoint}}` coming from the environment file? If you have 6 requests and each one has a `pm.sendRequest` inside it - Isn't that 12?

Comment: I don't see how that `pm.sendRequest` would have ever worked like that in the UI the way you're referencing the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `Tests` tab and then export the collection:

```
pm.sendRequest(`${pm.environment.get('endpoint')}/products/4`, (err, response) => {
    pm.test("Status code is 200", () => {
        pm.response.to.have.status(200)
    })
})
```

Using `{{endpoint}}` in that tab wouldn't know what to reference.

You can only use them in that way on the URL, URL parameters, headers, authorization, request body, and header presets.

[Accessing Variables in the Request Builder](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables#accessing-variables-in-the-request-builder)